# Is it possible to set an unlimited number of Call Logs and SMS on Samsung Galaxy A10?

Tags: samsung, backup, sms, call-history, samsung-one-ui

I have a backup using [SMS Backup & Restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore) for a long time. But, the number of Call Logs stopped at 2000 and didn't increase. I thought it was a limit of the free version, but I found it on the [official site](https://www.synctech.com.au/faqs/why-does-the-app-only-back-up-500-call-logs/):

> The app does not have any restrictions on the number of call logs it backs up, however, most phones only keep a limited number of calls (500 or 1000 or 2000) in memory and the app can only backup those call logs.

So, it is related to my mobile - [Samsung Galaxy A10](https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_a10-9580.php) - Android 10 (One UI 2)

Is it possible to set it to unlimited or at least rapidly increase? Call Logs. Of course, SMS also (SMS still increases (555), so the exact maximum number I don't know).